# 400 Bad Request when using @RequestBody on a AutoPopulatingList<T> attribute in a form submitted through JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, model-view-controller

I'm currently using an http ajax call to a server to submit a form. I'm using the latest Spring MVC and Angular for my presentation layer. When I submit the request, I get a 400 Bad Request error whenever I use a AutoPopulatingList attribute in my form class. It works if I remove it.

Here is the Form:

```
public class ShopAccountForm {
  protected AutoPopulatingList<ProfileFormField> profileFields = new AutoPopulatingList<ProfileFormField>(ProfileFormField.class);
}
```

Here is my Field in the form

```
public class ProfileFormField {
    private String fieldCode;
    private String value;

    public ProfileFormField(){

    }

    public String getFieldCode() {
        return fieldCode;
    }

    public void setFieldCode(String fieldCode) {
        this.fieldCode = fieldCode;
    }

    public ProfileFormField(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Here is my Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody RestResponse<Object> post(@RequestBody @Valid ShopAccountForm form, BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors()){
        return RestResponse.forError(result);
    }
    /// do some processing
}
```

Here is the JSON

```
{"profileFields":[{"fieldCode":"FIRST_NAME","value":"Me"},{"fieldCode":"LAST_NAME","value":"Yeah"}]}
```

I tried converting the JSON to but it does not work:

```
 {"profileFields[0].fieldCode": "FIRST_NAME","profileFields[0].value": "Me""profileFields[1].fieldCode": "LAST_NAME","profileFields[1].value": "Yeah"}
```

Any idea on how to bind the AutoPopulatingList to a JSON request?

Thanks!

Comment: Turn your logs to DEBUG and show us what it prints.

Comment: To clarify for everyone is the 400 error appearing when you load the web page or when you make a ajax call to the post controller. Also looking at the controller what happens when there is no error, what do you return?

Comment: What happens if you use a simple List (ArrayList or some such)?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Let me turn on the debug mode and I'll post the results. Aeseir, the 400 error happens when the Ajax call is made and the POST is sent to the controller. The Form and page renders fine without errors. Taylor I'm using AutoPopulatingList because I don;t have control over the many fields that the form will render dynamically. This approach was taken from http://eggsylife.co.uk/2009/11/30/spring-forms-dynamic-lists-and-ajax/

Comment: Why would you need an auto populating list anyway? You are using JSON and RequestBody so everything is reconstructed each time a request comes in. You would need a auto populating list only if you use classic form binding with AJAX... So in short you are making it too complex with this list just use a normal list.

Answer (score 0):

Create setters and getters in ShopAccountForm class and it will work.